# HTML5 video previous - next and auto play

Tags: javascript, html, video

I'm new to this site and I am new to HTML5 and Javascript aswell. 
It's not that I am a beginner, I kinda understand HTML5 and Javascript when I see it, I just can't write it proper myself.

I have many videos, all mp4, all same size, all in the same folder on the server. 
I already got them to play one after another without break. I don't have any controls. 
Looks like this (a code I found and copied and changed as far as I understood it):

**BODY**

```
<video id="homevideo" width="1022px" height="766px" autoplay onended="run()">
    <source src="video1.mp4" type='video/mp4'/>
</video>
```

**SCRIPT**

```
<script>
video_count =1;
videoPlayer = document.getElementById("homevideo");

function run(){
        video_count++;
        if (video_count == 16) video_count = 1;
        var nextVideo = "video"+video_count+".mp4";
        videoPlayer.src = nextVideo;
        videoPlayer.play();
   };
   </script>
```

It all looks like this now: 
[Presentation](http://www.test.pluskat.de/video/try/)

What I want: 
I want a previous and a next function.
So, I have two buttons, a previous and a next button. When I click on the next button, the next video will start and play automatically (no loop). When I click on previous button, the previous video will play again (no loop). So I can simply switch between all my videos forward and backwards. 
Like this for example: 
[IMAGE](http://i.imagebanana.com/img/ov3jgut2/idee.JPG)

What do I have to add to my code? What to change? I know hot do make buttons ect. 
Would be nice if someone could give me a clear code for this. Nothing with play or pause or anything.

Thanks very much!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First step is to add an event handler to each button. For example, something like this should work for your next button.

```
  var el = document.getElementById("nextButton");
  if (el.addEventListener) {
      el.addEventListener("click", yourNextFunction, false);
  } else {
      el.attachEvent('onclick', yourNextFunction);
  }
```

Then you need to write the yourNextFunction function to move to the next video. You can base this on your existing code.

```
var video_count =1,
    videoPlayer = document.getElementById("homevideo");

function yourNextFunction (){
      video_count++;
      if (video_count == 16) video_count = 1;
      var nextVideo = "video"+video_count+".mp4";
      videoPlayer.src = nextVideo;
      videoPlayer.play();
}
```

You can then do something similar for the previous button.

Comment: Thank you very much! Works perfectly fine. Now I only need to make the previous one happen. Will update here once I got it to work.

Comment: Question: Where would I have to insert the load() code so it would load the next/previous video in advance?

Comment: @MatthiasGies That would be more difficult with a single video tag. You might need a separate tag for current, previous and next which you can hide until it is needed. Probably a bit beyond th escope of this question so might be better off asking a new one :)

Answer (score 0):

```js
<script>
    var videocount =1;
 var player=document.getElementById('homevideo');
    player.addEventListener('ended',dispositor);
    function dispositor(x){
    if(!x) 
    { x = window.event; }
 videocount++;      
 if (videocount > 2){ // last number of video playing in loop. 
 videocount = 1;}  
 player.src="video"+videocount+".mp4"; //complete url
}
</script>
```

```html
<video id="homevideo" autoplay="" controls webkit-playsinline="" width="100%" height="100%" >
<source src="video1.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

Comment: Hi @TomGlendestam and welcome to SO! I would suggest you take a look at the [how to answer page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) to understand the expectations of a good answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try with the code below:

```
<video id="homevideo" autoplay="" controls webkit-playsinline="" width="100%" height="100%" >
 <source src="video1.mp4" type="video/mp4"> 
 <script>
   video_count =1; 
   videoPlayer = document.getElementById("homevideo");
   function run(){
     video_count++;
     if (video_count == 16)
       video_count = 1;
     var nextVideo = "video"+video_count+".mp4";
     videoPlayer.src = nextVideo;
     videoPlayer.play();
   };
 </script>
 </source>
</video>
```