# I need help getting files from a folder on the server and using their path as the source for my video tag

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, directory-listing

Basically what I've got planned here is this:

```
let vid1 = "/videos/introduction.mp4";
let vid2 = "/videos/explanation.mp4";
let vid3 = "/videos/conclusion.mp4";

// Next video function

let video_count = 1;

if (nextBtn.addEventListener) {
  nextBtn.addEventListener("click", nextVideo, false);
} else {
  nextBtn.attachEvent("onclick", nextVideo);
}

function nextVideo() {
  video_count++;
  if (video_count == 16) video_count = 1;
  let nextVid  = "vid" + video_count;
  video.src = nextVid;
}

// Previous video function

previousBtn.addEventListener("click", prevVideo);
function prevVideo() {
  video_count--;
  if (video_count == 0) video_count = 1;
  // THIS LINE is the problem
  let prevVid = "vid" + video_count;
  video.src = prevVid;
}
```

In both `let = nextVid` and `let = prevVid` I want it so that the video source is set to the **vid2** variable, but it displays it as *.../videos/vid2*. I want it to be *.../videos/explanation.mp4*. Removing the quotation marks makes **vid** `undefined`, but if I try to define it I won't know what to code from there as I'm not familiar with arrays.

My current code has been modified from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19564708/html5-video-previous-next-and-auto-play).

I also tried using Node.js but I don't know how to display the directory listing onto the server. I'm just starting out JS and I understand it pretty well and still learning so corrections and criticism are greatly appreciated.

Comment: `let nextVid  = "vid" + video_count; video.src = nextVid;` - you are not dynamically accessing your numbered variable names here, you are assigning a _literal_ value like `vid1` here. Whenever you are tempted to use "numbered" variable names, that is a very strong indicator that you should be using an array instead in the first place.

Comment: How would I do that. I'm not particularly familiar with arrays, could you please give me an example maybe I can base it off of that.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/First_steps/Arrays